# slf4j: write the ERROR, WARN and INFO logs to the file

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I am using slf4j to log my application. In the backlog.xml file I would like to write every thing  except the debug logs. How can I do it in my case? Also I want to write the error, info and warn logs.

I would appreciate any help!

logback.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE logback>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_ROOT" value="c:/temp/logs" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE_NAME" value="application" />

    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -
                %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_ROOT}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -
                %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.integration" level="INFO"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

    <logger name="com.integration" level="ERROR"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code from the internet and it worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE logback>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_ROOT" value="c:/temp/logs" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE_NAME" value="application" />

    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_ROOT}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.common" level="INFO"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```